# Extracting the data of each frame from an AVI file

Tags: import, data, video

What's the most straightforward way to "Import" the data of an AVI video? 
For instance, if I record a 30 frame per second video, then after 10 seconds I would have 300 frames. How can I import the data of all frames at once (without running of the memory)?

Comment: Have you seen [the docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/AVI.html)?

Comment: @J.M. Yes. But I want to extract the pixel values of each frame.

Comment: `Import[yourvideo, {"AVI", "ImageList"}]` will produce a list of still images, which you can then process further as you wish.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks, already tried. But is there anyway to directly extract the data? or at list instead of Import, Export the image list?

Comment: I recommend using FFmpeg to convert video to images (example [here](http://superuser.com/a/729351/203152)), then use Mathematica to import images. Mathematica seems slow to me to work on video directly.

Comment: faf, `ImageData` can be applied to each image / frame to obtain an array containing the pixel values. However, I would concur with @xslittlegrass that *Mathematica* can be very slow when working with videos. What do you need to do with the data after you import it? Perhaps there's another, more efficient way.

Comment: @MarcoB I want to get the pixel values out of each frame.

Comment: @xslittlegrass I already tried it. Downloading the package, installing it (flie>install>FFmpeg.m) and then summoned it via "Needs". I got this error: "Cannot import data as \!\(\"JSON\"\) format. "

Comment: You want to extract the pixel values of each frames and do what? If your goal is really to have a list of pixel values, then `ImageData /@ Import[yourvideo, {"AVI", "ImageList"}]` is the best you can do. If your goal is to do something more specific, then there might be other solutions. Also you should say in your question what you have tried and what the problem with that was.

Comment: @C.E. But by using the mentioned command, the computer crashed due to lack of memory. (OS:64bit. Memory:4GB). Afterwards I can analyse the frames as images.

Comment: @faf I understand that, which is why I mentioned two things in my previous comment that will help us help you. If you don't have memory enough on your computer to hold all frames in memory at once, then you can't import all frames at once. It's an impossible question.

Comment: @faf I have provided an example in the answer below. Hope it will be hopeful.

Comment: @C.E.  What should I add to this code to get for instance the 40th framce data instead of all of them at once? `ImageData /@ Import[yourvideo, {"AVI", "ImageList"}]`

Comment: @faf Look in the documentation for "AVI", under "Elements".

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) to convert a video to images and import them into Mathematica. I'm using the [jfkrice.avi](http://er.jsc.nasa.gov/seh/jfkrice.avi) video as an example.

This will convert the video to a list of images

```
ffmpeg -i jfkrice.avi -r 10 -f image2 jfkrice/%05d.png
```

the number `10` means 10 images per second.

Then we can use Mathematica to import them

```
imgls = Import /@ FileNames["jfkrice/*.png"];
```

Now you can manipulate the images, for example, make an edge detected image3D object:

```
Image3D[EdgeDetect /@ imgls]
```

[image]

Comment: From the [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6VqrY.png) in the answer I did expect a video about something like an internal-combustion engine but found a video with Bill Klinton. :(

Comment: Actually, it is John F Kennedy :)